# Zabbix external checks cannot be executed due to SELinux

Tags: zabbix, selinux

I try to implement external checks in Zabbix 2.2. I've created simple bash script for SSL verification which should be executed by zabbix service. The script is located in /var/lib/zabbixsrv/externalchecks directory. Even if there are 777 permission for the .sh script I still receive message telling

```
unable to execute /var/lib/zabbixsrv/externalscripts/test.sh: Permission denied
```

I've got same message when I try to run the command even as root. The `ls -Z /var/lib/zabbixsrv/externalscripts/test.sh` command output says:

```
-rwxrwxrwx. zabbixsrv zabbixsrv unconfined_u:object_r:default_t:s0 /var/lib/zabbixsrv/externalscripts/test.sh
```

There is no message relating this in /var/log/massages. Does anybody know how to force selinux to allow execute zabbixsrv user the script without disabling selinux?

Which zabbix service (zabbix-server, zabbix-agent, ...) should execute the external checks script?

Comment: This question is better suited for Server Fault than Stack Overflow as it is an administration question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main issue was in `/etc/fstab` configuration file. The Zabbix has defined as default values for script `/var/lib/zabbixsrv/excernalscripts` directory. My server has /var mounted with `rw` and `noexec` permissions.

I've already moved the script to different location and change the configuration file accordingly. Checks are working fine now.

Thanks everybody for any contribution relating this topic.

Answer (score 0):

Did you tried to set `AllowRoot=1` in `/etc/zabbix/zabbix_agentd.conf`?